# How to programmatically change page name and url in SharePoint 2010 with EventReceiver

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, eventreceiver

What I want to achieve is simple. When user create a new page in SharePoint 2010, I want to remove special character and truncate the page Name/URL to a certain number of characters.

Eg: user type in "I Want To Create This Page With An Extra Long Name !@#$%^^&**_+" in the create new page dialogbox, the actual page that get create is "extralongname.aspx"

I got the remove special character and truncate part. I just can't change the page Name/Url.

Any idea?

Regards,

Ken

Comment: Hmm, it has been more than a week and no one reply. Does this mean no one in the whole world know the answer (even from Microsoft) or the problem is too hard to solve?

Answer (score 0):

I found your question by searching for an simliar problem.

I guess you've solved the problem in the meantime. Maybe it can help other people having the same issue.

Are you doing this with the SPSecurity Object?

eg.

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate(){
SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl); //You need the url here

   using(SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
   {
      web.Title = "The new Title";
      web.Update();
   }

});
```

It's because the user may not have the privileges doing this.

But this should do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

It is really easy. You just have to change the value of field `FileLeafRef`.

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("https://sharepoint-site.domain.com"))
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
{
    SPList list = web.Lists["Your list"];
    SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(1);

    // next row is important
    item[SPBuiltInFieldId.FileLeafRef] = "Your page url and title.aspx";
    item.Update();
}
```